# Mongoose Pagination too slow to query over hundreds of record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have implemented mongoose pagination to fasten up the query and on the UI(Angular) I have pagination there which recives data from this route. But it is still very slow when I change the page

page 1 loads at good speed but when I change the page it takes lots of time to fetch. let say from page 1 to page 5 it takes 1.25min to load the data.

here is my code

```
router.get("/report",cache(30), (req, res) => {
  var page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
  const pageSize = 5;
  Reports.find({}).then(requests => {
    const pager = paginate(requests.length, page, pageSize);
    const pageOfitems = requests.slice(pager.startIndex, pager.endIndex + 1);
    return res.status(200).json({
      pager,
      pageOfitems
    })
  })
});
```

You can see I have implemnted Cache as well but that didn't speed up the performance

Comment: As seen, you are loading all the records from your collection. and then you are trying to paginate. However you should load only the limited records and then request for another set. This can be done using $skip operator of mongodb.

Comment: can you give some example of it?

Comment: yes, i will provide shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going for find query, you can use aggregate query and you can limit the records you want and skip the record you want to skip. for example lets say with first request you want to load only 10 records. in this case you will skip 0 records and limit 10. on the next pagination request you will skip 10 records and limit 10 again.
Here is one such example https://mongoplayground.net/p/fCtlTBazdY6

```
Reports.aggregate()
.skip(page)
.limit(pageSize)
.exec().then(....
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I have total 100 records, and currently shows only 5 records per page... but from the code above it is now showing only 5 records in total and pagination is only showing first page in the view unless I change the page URL query =2 or query = 3

Comment: here is what I did:

`router.get("/report",cache(30), (req, res) => {
  var page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
  const pageSize = 5;
  Reports.aggregate().skip(page).limit(pageSize).exec().then(requests => {
    const pager = paginate(requests.length, page, pageSize);
    const pageOfitems = requests.slice(pager.startIndex, pager.endIndex + 1);
    return res.status(200).json({
      pager,
      pageOfitems
    })
  })
});`

Comment: change it to this.  Reports.aggregate()
.skip(page)
.limit(pageSize)
.exec().then(requests =>{
return res.status(200).json({requests })
})

Comment: we will discuss about pager, but first do this and see what output you get. I am sure it will be fast now

Comment: yes it has speed perfomance! but now pagination does not work

Comment: We will do that in short!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197935/discussion-between-sachin-vishwakarma-and-muhammad-ali).